# Android Studio Missing initial partition file:

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: /Users/ChristopherTruong/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_24.avd/userdata.img
```

I have tried reinstalling HAXM, android studio, completely removing all android studio files, and reinstalling yet it still doesn't work. I've tried tweaking with advanced settings, deleting the AVD yet it still doesn't fix the issue. I searched through out stack overflow and none of the solutions help me.

Comment: The Python tag shouldn't be applied to this question unless the problem is related to the Python language

Comment: Did you download SDK manager api 24 everything

Comment: Please update your question to provide more information about the error. For example: When does it occur?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you managed to solve this. I am facing something similar. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some hours I managed to get it solved. The problem for me was related to the **GPU** drivers - it seems that the Android Studio emulator uses GPU acceleration.

Just uninstalling and reinstalling the GPU drivers did the trick for me.

For reference I have am using an Intel i7 6700K CPU and the on-board GPU.

Hope it helps

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows? I am getting the same error on Mac and never on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and it would not go away after the first boot attempt, as suggested on related posts. I solved it by upgrading to the latest Emulator version still in Canary channel: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/06/emulator-2736-canary.html
You can switch to Canary by doing the following: Go to SDKManager in Android Studio, then Updates > change to Canary channel, refresh, then go to the  Android SDK > SDK Tools tab and selectively update the "Android Emulator" item (check it and hit Apply).